# Should I each time change my teamcity configuration after creating a new branch?

Tags: teamcity-5.1

I am following the [following structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668992.aspx) to re-structure my source-control project. Now I am also using TeamCity as my CI server. The configuration in TeamCity points to a specific tfs path in order to build the project. If I create a new branch, then I would also need to change the TFS path and eventually create a new TeamCity configuration. I am not sure if this is the proper way to do this. How do you manage your teamcity configuration when you branch?